# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field by reflection for persistent property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot (v 2.4.0) with Hibernate 5.4.24 and, when trying to get some information from my database, I keep getting this error message:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private int es.uc3m.orders.model.Shoppingcart.usID] by reflection for persistent property [es.uc3m.orders.model.Shoppingcart#usID] : 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int es.uc3m.orders.model.Shoppingcart.usID] by reflection for persistent property [es.uc3m.orders.model.Shoppingcart#usID] : 1
```

It is kind of weird for me, because it only happens when I try to access the table Shoppingcart, since I can get informatin from the rest of the tables.

I also used the exact same entities with another project but, insetad of using Spring Boot, persistence was made with EntityManagers and it worked perfectly fine.

These are my entities:

Shoppingcart

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Shoppingcart.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM Shoppingcart s")
public class Shoppingcart implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int scID;
    
    private int usID;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Product
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="sc_has_product"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="scID")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="productID")
            }
        )
    private List<Product> products;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to User
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="shoppingcart")
    private User user;

    public Shoppingcart() {
    }

    public int getScID() {
        return this.scID;
    }

    public void setScID(int scID) {
        this.scID = scID;
    }
    
    public int getusID() {
        return this.usID;
    }

    public void setusID(int usID) {
        this.usID = usID;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    
    public boolean isNull() {
        return getProducts().isEmpty();
        }
```

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String address;

    @Column(name="card_n")
    private Long cardN;

    private String city;

    private String country;

    private int cvv;

    private String email;

    private String exp;

    private String name;

    private String pass;

    private String surname1;

    private String surname2;
    
    private String typeOfUser;

    @Column(name="zip_code")
    private int zipCode;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Order
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Orders> orders;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Product
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Product> products;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Shoppingcart
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="usID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Shoppingcart shoppingcart;
    
    public User() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Long getCardN() {
        return this.cardN;
    }

    public void setCardN(Long cardN) {
        this.cardN = cardN;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getCvv() {
        return this.cvv;
    }

    public void setCvv(int cvv) {
        this.cvv = cvv;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getExp() {
        return this.exp;
    }

    public void setExp(String exp) {
        this.exp = exp;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return this.pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getSurname1() {
        return this.surname1;
    }

    public void setSurname1(String surname1) {
        this.surname1 = surname1;
    }

    public String getSurname2() {
        return this.surname2;
    }

    public void setSurname2(String surname2) {
        this.surname2 = surname2;
    }

    public int getZipCode() {
        return this.zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(int zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public List<Orders> getOrders() {
        return this.orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Orders> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    public Orders addOrder(Orders order) {
        getOrders().add(order);
        order.setUser(this);

        return order;
    }

    public Orders removeOrder(Orders order) {
        getOrders().remove(order);
        order.setUser(null);

        return order;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public Product addProduct(Product product) {
        getProducts().add(product);
        product.setUser(this);

        return product;
    }

    public Product removeProduct(Product product) {
        getProducts().remove(product);
        product.setUser(null);

        return product;
    }

    public Shoppingcart getShoppingcart() {
        return this.shoppingcart;
    }

    public void setShoppingcart(Shoppingcart shoppingcart) {
        this.shoppingcart = shoppingcart;
    }

    public String getTypeOfUser() {
        return typeOfUser;
    }

    public void setTypeOfUser(String typeOfUser) {
        this.typeOfUser = typeOfUser;
    }

}
```

This is the ShoppingcartDAO class:

```
public interface ShoppingCartDAO extends CrudRepository<Shoppingcart, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Shoppingcart s JOIN User u ON u.id = s.usID AND u.id LIKE :id")
    Shoppingcart findByUser(@Param("id") int id);
    
    @Query("SELECT s FROM Shoppingcart s")
    List<Shoppingcart> findAllShoppingCart();
}
```

And, finally, this is my ShoppingcartController class:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ShoppingCartController {

    @Autowired
    ShoppingCartDAO scDAO;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "sc", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> assignShoppingCart(@RequestBody(required = true) Shoppingcart sc) {
        try {
            scDAO.save(sc);
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "sc", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getEveryShoppingCart() {
        try {
            List<Shoppingcart> sc = scDAO.findAllShoppingCart();
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Shoppingcart>>(sc, (sc != null) ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

I am really going nuts as I can´t figure out what is going on with my code, so thank you in advance if you help me.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it. For those of you who are wondering how, I deleted the relationships between tables that I had, ending with:

Shoppingcart:

```
@Entity
public class Shoppingcart implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int scID;
    
    @Column(name = "usID")
    private Integer userID;

    public Shoppingcart() {
    }

    public int getScID() {
        return this.scID;
    }

    public void setScID(int scID) {
        this.scID = scID;
    }

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
```

Product:

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int productID;

    private String category;
    
    private String color;

    private String description;

    private String estadoProducto;

    private String fecha;
    
    private int orderID;

    private String photo;

    private double price;
    
    private int seller;

    private String sexo;

    private String state = "Disponible";

    private String talla;

    private String title;

    public Product() {
    }

    public int getProductID() {
        return this.productID;
    }

    public void setProductID(int productID) {
        this.productID = productID;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    
    public String getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getEstadoProducto() {
        return this.estadoProducto;
    }

    public void setEstadoProducto(String estadoProducto) {
        this.estadoProducto = estadoProducto;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return this.fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return this.photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return this.sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getTalla() {
        return this.talla;
    }

    public void setTalla(String talla) {
        this.talla = talla;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public void setOrderID(int orderID) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
    }

    public int getSeller() {
        return seller;
    }

    public void setSeller(int seller) {
        this.seller = seller;
    }
```

With this, everything worked fine, but don't ask me why, because I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Getters/Setters are wrongly implemented.

Like :

Actual :

```
public int getusID() {
        return this.usID;
    }
```

Expected :

```
public int getUsID() {
        return this.usID;
    }
```

*Same with setter*

Comment: That was right, but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Edit the Question with new details, bcz after correcting getters/setters it should work.
Try clearing your cache once.